# How can I make parallax working in Firefox?

Tags: sass

I have a [working parallax example](https://codepen.io/mysth/full/dyXrNzd) on Chrome on Codepen. The most important code is here :

```
body {
  height                     : $body-height;
  perspective                : #{$perspective}px;
  perspective-origin         : 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch; // Safari fix
}

@at-root body,
.parallax-container {
  overflow-x : hidden;
  overflow-y : auto;
  position   : relative;
}

@at-root body {
  @at-root .parallax-container {
    // position
    transform-style : preserve-3d; // to avoid that the intermediary container flattens the effect

    // size
    height : 100%;
    width  : 100%;

    @at-root {
      .background-content,
      .foreground-content {
        position : relative;
      }

      .background-content {
        transform-origin : 0 0;
        transform        : translateZ(0) scale(1);
      }

      div.other-class {
        $value           : 126;
        height           : #{$value}px;
        bottom           : #{-($value + 35)}px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I read a lot of things on parallax and still does not understand what is going wrong here.
I believe I made it work one time, maybe it is a regression, but I cannot find the problem.
Do not hesitate to suggest things for Safari if it does not work on Safari too because I cannot test it on this browser yet.

I am on Firefox 82.0.3 and Chromium 86.0.4240.198 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If I had found the root of the problem or if it was not hard ...I probably won't have posted this...You are not helping. But I will not force you to help me. If you need some specific things, I can add them but your comment is not useful at all. No offense.

Comment: If you want to get a quick answer, you should provide the problem or a working example, nobody knows how your chunk of CSS integrates with HTML, the problem may not even be in CSS

Comment: The working example is provided via the CodePen link, at least it works on Chrome as I said... So unless you do not know what is parallax, it would be pretty obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Its still unclear what the problem is, and by working example I assumed a website where parallax works

Comment: So an iframe is not sufficient for you ? Because in that link, if you opened it with Chrome, you will see the parallax and if you open the development tools, you'll see the related HTML and the CSS. You can even maybe copy the iframe code to put it in a local example on your computer if you wish.

Comment: Refer to my original comment